# Permission denied (publickey). Could not read from remote repository

Tags: ssh, git, android, github, android-studio

I am using android studio 3.6 and i can't find the SSH executable option when i navigate to file >> settings >> Version Control >> Git.

I am getting this error when i try to push a project to github:

Successfully created project 'xxxxxxxxx' on GitHub, but initial push failed: Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'xxxxxxxxxx' to the list of known hosts. git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). Could not read from remote repository.  Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this problem. When I use new 3.6 canary edition git operations are failing. On 3.5 stable version I turned on ssh executable -> native and all worked.